# First byte of string ends up unexpectedly being null

Tags: assembly, mips

I wrote the following code to calculate the length of a string:

```
strlen:
   # PROLOGUE
    subu $sp, $sp, 8
    sw $ra, 8($sp)
    sw $fp, 4($sp)
    addu $fp, $sp, 8

   # BODY
    #string stored at a0 at the start
    li $v0, 4
    syscall #print string

    li $v0, 0 #starts counter over

    andi $a2, $a0, 0xff    #obtain first byte
    j while

while:
    beqz $a2, ret #exit if null byte encountered
    srl $a0, $a0, 8 #shift to next byte
    andi $a2, $a0, 0xff #obtain first byte again
    add $v0, $v0, 1 #increment counter to be returned
    j while

ret:
    # EPILOGUE
    move $sp, $fp
    lw $ra, ($fp)
    lw $fp, -4($sp)
    jr $ra
```

It works by going through the string byte by byte and incrementing v0 until a null byte is encountered, whereupon control shifts to the label ret and the program ends. However, my function always seems to return 0, which means that v0 is never incremented, which means that a2 is 0 the moment the while loop begins. Why is this the case? I have verified that the input string is actually the string a0 contains via the printing syscall.

Comment: I would expect to see an `lb` or `lbu` in this function, but there appears to be none. `andi` does not load anything from memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

Remove the srl command and replace

```
andi $a2, $a0, 0xff #obtain first byte again
```

with

```
addu $a2, $a0, $v0
lbu  $a2, ($a2)
```

to load byte v0 of a0 after doing the address math.

v0 just has to be incremented before you call addu.

Comment: This makes even less sense.  Before I think you were looping over 4 bytes of string data in a register (rather than accepting a pointer arg).  Now you want to add integers from `v0` to that string data or pointer but still not `lb` from it?

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't need to load anything because the string is contained in a0 at the start. Treating a0 as a char array, addu peforms the move a2 = a0[v0], which is what I wanted.

Comment: If `a0` is a *pointer* to the start, `addu` gives you `a2 = &a0[v0]`.  If it's 4 contiguous bytes of string data (like if you did `memcpy(int_var, string, 4)`), it just modifies one of those bytes.  `addu` does *not* access memory, and it doesn't shift a higher byte to the bottom of the register.  If this works when you tested it, are you sure you don't have an `lb $a2, ($a2)` next?

Comment: @PeterCordes You're right. I used lbu but I didn't notice when making this post. To make sure there's nothing else I forgot to mention, I've edited the main post with how my code looks now.

Comment: Post answers as answers, not as edits to the question.  I fixed your answer to at least answer the question by including the load.  That was the point of my first comment.